# Database with hierarchy and joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has three tables in. Each is a heigharcy of the other. The tables are Dog, Gender, Name.

The Dog table includes the name of the breed and an id. The gender table includes an id of the dog breed, and id, and the sex. The name table includes the dogs name, the the gender id and how old it is.

The relationship is set up in the following manner. Dog -> Gender -> Name.

What would be the best way of pulling all the dogs names and sexes based off of just the dog id. I know i would have to use a join and I’m honestly not that proficient.

Psuedo code Ive came up with

JOIN NAME ON GENDER ON DOG. Is that correct?

### DOG

id, name, gender id, age

- 1, Holey, 2, 7
- 2, Fluffy, 1, 3

### GENDER

id, sex, breed id

- 1, male, 1
- 2, female, 1

### NAME

id, name, breed id

- 1, male, 1
- 2, female, 1

Comment: This really makes very little sense from a semantic POV. Can you provide some sample data? What does a row look like for each table?

Comment: Why did you split up the data in different tables? Looking at it logically i presume that one dog can only have one sex, one name, one gender, one age... Or am I overseeing something? I think you'd better put all the fields in one table.

Comment: The data is preset in that format

Comment: maybe its a transsexual dog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT Breed.Breed, Gender.Sex, Dog.Name FROM Dog 
JOIN Gender ON Dog.GenderID = Gender.ID 
JOIN Breed ON Gender.BreedID = Breed.ID
WHERE Dog.ID = 'YourDogIDHere'
```

And it would return the following:

Breed   | Sex   | Name
 --------|--------|-------
 Collie  | Male | Fluffy
 Collie  | Female | Holey

**Edit**: Edited to include breed and reorder columns.

Comment: how can i get it to return an array with the breed being first level, gender being second, and name being third

Comment: @user3708645, I added the breed in as well. Your pseudocode seemed a little funny for breed name, but if the table really is called name, then just substitute name for Breed

Comment: thank you for your help. For some reason it is returning name as the key in the array. with breed and sex inside of it. What I'm trying to do is group the breeds into categories with the dog names and ages under them. Then i have to find the mean age.

Comment: i figured it out thanks